# How to filter results based on relationships in query scope?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I am writing an application where I have two models namely `AngencyProfile`and `Ad`. I have created a polymorphic relationship of the both models.

The structure of the `ads table` is as follows:

[image: Schema]

I need to write query scope for `AngencyProfile` to retrieve the agency profiles based on criteria, lets say `where remaining_budget >= cpc`.

How can I achieve this? Or is it possible?

The relationship and query scope that I am writing now is as follows:

```
public function ads() {
    return $this->morphMany(Ad::class, 'advertisable');
}
public function scopeAdvertisable($query)
{
    return $query->ads()->where('remaining_budget', '>=', 'cpc)->get();
}
```

This is throwing an exception.

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::ads()

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need to create `Polymorphic relation` for these tables?

Comment: I have many other models that are advertisable... Can I improve relationships there?

Comment: Query scopes are supposed to be used to apply additional constraints on a query. Calling a relation method there simply does not make any sense and as you can see is impossible, so let us know what it is you're trying to achieve and we'll try to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try changing following function

```
public function scopeAdvertisable($query)
{
    return $query->ads()->where('remaining_budget', '>=', 'cpc)->get();
}
```

To

```
public function scopeAdvertisable($query)
{
    return $query->with(['ads'=> function($query){
        $query->where('remaining_budget', '>=', 'cpc);
    }])
    ->get();
}
```

### Update:

```
public function scopeAdvertisable($query)
    {
        return $query->whereHas('ads',function($query){
            $query->where('remaining_budget', '>=', 'cpc);
        })
        ->get();
    }
```

Comment: It is returning all the results... What should I do to fix it?

Comment: add one where query for scopeAdvertisable

Comment: first, try using `whereHas()` instead of with

Comment: Thank you Jaysingkar... You did a great help... :)

Comment: Welcome :-). Glad I could help.